# Dependencies in package.json - Multiple tarball URLs

Tags: node.js, npm

In `package.json` it is possible to specify a dependency using a URL (e.g. a git url or a tarball). [Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#urls-as-dependencies), [example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/54b5b62f78747d34bf325d490abb1a71d04f1ee9).

Is there a way to specify multiple fallback URLs in case the first one is not reachable?

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is not something that `npm` supports. Looking at your example, is it not possible to depend on `react@0.14.0-beta1` (which is the same as the commit you are currently depending on)?

Comment: Good question, not sure why we don't use that. Asked Ben Alpert.